# How do you get the id of an object inside a fields_for block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form similar to this:

```
=form_for @client do |c|
  =c.label :name
  =c.text_Field :name
  =c.fields_for :places do |p|
    =link_to p.object.location, edit_client_location_path(@client, p.object.id)
    =p.text_field :status
```

The `link_to` is supposed to open a window popup with the rest of the fields from the table `places`, so I require the `id` of the Location to include in `edit_client_location_path`, but I'm getting an error that `id` is nil.

The strange thing is that if I replace it with this:

```
    =link_to p.object.id, '#'
    =p.text_field :status
```

... I do get the id printed in the view. This error only happens if I include it in the `link_to` and the same happens for any other attribute.

I tried to save the id in a variable like so:

```
    -id=p.object.id
    =link_to p.object.location, edit_client_location_path(@client,id)
    =p.text_field :status
```

but I also get an error that it is nil. If I try to use `p.object.id.dup` I get an error that Fixnum cannot be dup. I'm so confused.

What am I missing? Is there a better way to access the id?

**UPDATE:**

As a workaround I'm now using

```
    =link_to p.object.location, "/clients/#{@client.id}/location/#{p.object.id}/edit"
```

For some reason, `p` will be nil when inside the `link_to`. I don't know if it's something else in my application doing this, I'll try to replicate this in a clean setup later.

Comment: if you using EDIT action, then either you need to pass instance or parameter with ID. So try with edit_client_location_path(id:@client.id, object_id:p.object.id)

Comment: This is so weird. I misspelled `client_id` in the `edit_client_location_path` link, and id actually worked, but as soon as I fixed the error, id went back to nil. I must be losing my mind.

Comment: so this is working or not?

Comment: It did not, `id` is still nil. If I misspell something else, `id` does actually get converted to its value, but then `edit_client_location_path` says that `client_id` is missing (obviously), but as soon as I put `client_id` back correctly, `id` goes back to nil.

Comment: Can you please share path with path params for  `edit_client_location_path`?

Comment: You mean an example of how it'd look? If the client.id was 3, and the location.id was 1 It'd be `/clients/3/location/1/edit`. The route is `/clients/:client_id/location/:id/edit(.:format)`

Answer (score 0):

Did u try this?

`edit_client_location_path(@client, p.object)`

Comment: Yup, didn't work. For some reason `p.object` is nil altogether when inside the `link_to` line.

Comment: I don't think that is the case, since your workaround is also using the same p.object inside the `link_to` method. Is it possible that one (but not all) of the places has `nil` id?

Comment: Oh, I know!!! It is not nil. However, when I use it within `edit_client_location_path`, the whole object equals to nil, only when used in `edit_client_location_path`. EDITED: Sorry. I meant the path, not `link_to`.

Comment: I think at this point, it would help if you share more of your relevant code snippets from controller, models, views and routes.